# Who asked Rav Moshe about capital punishment?

Tags: history, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, moshe-feinstein

There is an interesting *t'shuva* in *[Igros Moshe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igros_moshe#Works) Choshen Mishpat* vol.2 #68 ([pt. 1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14678&st=&pgnum=290) [pt. 2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14678&st=&pgnum=291)) in which he explains the extreme rarity of capital punishment in Jewish law, especially in modern times. It is addressed to a "*sar ham'dina*" (government official?) and opens and closes with very nice praises for the same. The *t'shuva* is dated Purim 1981.

Who was the questioner? How did he understand Rav Moshe's answer?

Comment: A post with the answer and some extra background form the man who wrote the Index to the Iggros Moshe http://daattorah.blogspot.com/2010/02/r-moshe-feinsteinlegitimacy-of-capital.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In 1981, [Hugh Carey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugh_Carey) was governor of New York.

According to Wikipedia:

> He is also remembered for preventing conservative legislators from reinstating the death penalty

So the subject of the death penalty would certainly have been on his mind.

My understanding of the responsum is Rav Moshe is not weighing in pro or con per se regarding what the State of New York's stance should be; he is simply explaining and defending the theoretical use of the death penalty in the Torah. I don't know who translated the letter to English, whether Governor Carey read it, or if it affected his decision process in any way. (Rabbi Aaron Soloveichik, in contrast, was quite vociferously opposed to any modern-day death penalty.)

There are several indicators that the letter was addressed to the governor:

- The language *Sar HaMedina*. See for instance the [prayer for the US found in the *Tikun Meir* siddur](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1627/who-wrote-the-1950s-era-super-patriotic-prayer-for-the-united-states-of-america), which blesses "president so-and-so", "vice-president so-and-so", the country's legislators and justices; and then *sar hamedina* and his/her second-in-command; followed finally by "the head of this city" (*rosh ha'ir hazot*). By context, then, *sar hamedina v'mishnehu* must refer to the governor of the state (and his/her lieutenant governor).
- I am not aware of any other executive who would have been reconsidering the death penalty in 1981. I don't believe the mayor of NYC, nor the president of the US, was doing so; and the language sounds as it it's addressed to an executive, not a legislator or justice.
- The letter concludes with blessings to *sar hamedina* for his continued successful leadership "*within* this wonderful country of the United States of America", implying that *sar hamedina* is not himself the president of the US.

Comment: My upvote for, AFAICT, sound reasoning. However: In 1981, there were forty-nine other governors in the U.S. (Not to mention presidents and prime ministers elsewhere.) I think that the wording of the _t'shuva_ makes it sound like _Rav Moshe_ was a constituent of the recipient's, but this answer might mention that.

Comment: "Presidents and prime ministers elsewhere" -- couldn't be; he concludes about the addressee's great work "within the US." But fair enough, theoretically it could have been a different governor who was mulling over the death penalty in 1981; but I don't think so. I doubt it's so much a constituency thing as many states with smaller Jewish populations  wouldn't care much about the Jewish view, or wouldn't value Rav Moshe's voice as that of Judaism.

Comment: Right about presidents and prime ministers: my mistake. Also possibly, even likely, right about other governors' not caring as much. But I think there is indication _Rav Moshe_ was a constituent, in the opening words _v'hachaviv alenu_. Who are "us" in that phrase if not the recipients' constituents? (Elsewhere in the _t'shuva_, in fact in the next sentence, _Rav Moshe_ refers to himself in the singular, so I doubt _v'hachaviv alenu_ refers to himself alone.)

Comment: "(Rabbi Aaron Soloveichik, in contrast, was quite vociferously opposed to any modern-day death penalty.)" Source?

Comment: @SethJ it's well-known. The Gemara says they stopped the death penalty when the Sanhedrin was exiled from the Temple office; R' Aaron felt that meant *no* government could use capital punishment from that point on. I've heard this from his talmidim, and I believe also on a yutorah shiur ... but sorry I can't pinpoint a written source at the moment.

Comment: @Shalom, that's fine.  I just wanted to know if it was purely hearsay, or if it was common-knowledge of his position, based on his Shi'urim, which may or may not be available to listen to, or if he'd written it somewhere. Sounds like B.