# Listing acts of patriotism towards a host nation

Tags: minhag, history

In the UK, united synagogues recite a prayer for the royal family including a blessing for "all her advisors and councillers" that they may grant us peace, etc. Many synagogues also display British flags on significant dates or make additional prayers for significant national occasions.

Are there other examples of nationalistic pride or patriotism, both from the past and in the modern era?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9283/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9276/759

Comment: Why use the term "host nation"?

Answer (score 3):

Tons and tons of them are out there. (I'm making this a wiki so people can expand.)

- [Prayer service to mark 50 years of the reign of archduke Karl Theodore in Germany.](http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2011/12/schutzjuden-thank-karl-theodor.html)
- [Hallel on Israel's Independence Day and on Jerusalem Day](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25986)
- [Super-patriotic prayer for the United States composed over 50 years ago](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1627/who-wrote-the-1950s-era-super-patriotic-prayer-for-the-united-states-of-america)
- [Beautiful prayer for Australia](http://www.shira.org.au/prayer-for-australia/) said at Shira Chadasha, Melbourne
- Hallel on Thanksgiving (by a few American congregations)

Answer (score 1):

**"A Prayer for the Government"** by [Rabbi Louis Ginzberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Ginzberg), 1927

> אֱלֹהֵינוּ וֵאלֹהֵי אֲבוֹתֵֽינוּ קַבֵּל נָא בְּרַחַמִים
>   אֶת־תְּפִלָּתֵֽנוּ בְּעַד אַרְצֵֽנוּ וּמֶמְשַׁלְתָּהּ. הָרֵק
>   אֶת־בּרְכָתְךָ ע֚ל הָאָֽרֶץ הַזֺּאת עַל נְשִׂיאָהּ שׁוֹפְטֶֽיהָ
>   שׁוֹטְרֶֽיהָ וּפְקִידֶֽהָ הָעוֹסְקִים בְצָרְכֵי צִבּוּר בֶּאֱמוּנָה.
>   הוֹרֵם מֵחֻקֵּי תוֺרָתֶֽךָ הַבִינֵם מִשְׁפְּטֵי צִדְקֶֽךָ לְמַֽעַן לֺא
>   יָסוּרוּ מֵאַרְצֵֽנוּ שָׁלוֹם וְשַׁלְוָה אֺֽשֶׁר וָחֺֽפֶשׁ
>   כּל־הַיָּמִים. אָנָּא יְיָ אֱלֺהֵי הָרוּחוֺת לְכָל־בָּשָׂר שְׁלַח
>   רוּחֲךָ עַל כָּל־תּוֹשְׁבֵי אַרְצֵֽנוּ וְטַע בֵּין בְּנֵי הָאֻמּוֹת
>   וְהָאֱמוּנוֹת הַשּׁוֹנוֹת הַשּׁוֹכְנִים בָּהּ אַהֲבָה וְאַחֲוָה שׁלוֹם
>   וְרֵעוּת. וַעֲקֺר נִלִּבָּם כָל שִׂנְאָה וְאֵיבָה קִנְאָה וְתַחֲרוּת.
>   לְמַלֺּאות מַשָּׂא נֶֽפשׁ בָּנֶֽיהָ הַמִּתְיַמְְּרִים בִּכְבוֹדָהּ
>   וְהַמִּשְׁתּוֹקְקִים לִרְאוֹתָהּ אוֹר לְכָל־הַגּוֹיִם.‏
>
> וְכֵן יְהִי רָצוֹן מִלְּפָנֶֽיךָ שֶׁתְּהֵא אַרְצֵֽנוּ בְּרָכָה
>   לְכָל־יוֹשְׁבֵי תֵבֵל וְתַשְׁרֶה בֵּינֵיהֶם רֵעוּת וְחֵרוּת וְקַיֵּם
>   בִּמְהֵרָה חֲזוֹן נְבִיאֶֽיךָ “לֹא־יִשָּׂ֨א ג֤וֹי אֶל־גּוֹי֙ חֶ֔רֶב
>   וְלֹא־יִלְמְד֥וּ ע֖וֹד מִלְחָמָֽה” וְנֶאֱמַר “כִּֽי־כוּלָּם֩ יֵדְע֨וּ
>   אוֹתִ֜י לְמִקְטַנָּ֤ם וְעַד־גְּדוֹלָם֙ נְאֻם־יְהוָ֔ה כִּ֤י אֶסְלַח֙
>   לַֽעֲוֹנָ֔ם וּלְחַטָּאתָ֖ם לֹ֥א אֶזְכָּר־עֽוֹד”. אָמֵן׃

---

> Our God and God of our ancestors: We ask Your blessings for our
>   country, for its government, for its leader and advisors, and for all
>   who exercise just and rightful authority. Teach them insights of Your
>   Torah, that they may administer all affairs of state fairly, that
>   peace and security, happiness and prosperity, justice and freedom may
>   forever abide in our midst.
>
> Creator of all flesh, bless all the inhabitants of our country with
>   Your spirit. May citizens of all races and creeds forge a common bond
>   in true harmony to banish all hatred and bigotry and to safeguard the
>   ideals and free institutions which are the pride and glory of our
>   country.
>
> May this land under Your Providence be an influence for good
>   throughout the world, uniting all people in peace and freedom and
>   helping them to fulfill the vision of Your prophet: "Nation shall not
>   lift up sword against nation, neither shall they experience war any
>   more." And let us say: Amen.

Comment: My large and well known Modern Orthodox synagogue announces the names and home towns of US Service men and women--Jew and non-Jew-who died during the past week. In addition, prayers are offered for those missing in action.