# Why doesn't Chabad say Hanotein Teshua

Tags: tefilla, nuschaot, politics-government, nusach-ari

In many siddurim, particularly those printed for the Ashkenazi or Spanish-Portuguese communities, there is a tefillah for the government, Hanotein Teshuah (the title is based on a passuk in Ps. 144) printed after the Mi Shebeirach for the community

However, in the current Chabad siddur, there is no such prayer (it goes right from the above-mentioned Mi Shebeirach to Birchat Hachodesh [pg. 232]). Why is this?

---

None of the Chabads I have davened at say a prayer for the government, whereas every other schul I have been to on Shabbat does.

Comment: "every other schul I have been to on Shabbat does": your experience vastly differs from mine.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted practice in chabad is not to add tefilos during davening that were not included in the siddur by the Alter Rebbe. That being said without knowing more about the specific prayer there wouldn't be a reason necessary that one could not recite it after davening.

Comment: Hanotein Teshua is a tefillah for the government, which, according to the bottom comment here <http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1868/4504> was printed in previous editions.

Comment: sounds questionable at best. He would need to back up his answer with a source or a picture of the text. Also earlier versions of the nusach arizal used by chabad were not called Tehilas Hashem. One example being Sidur Torah Ohr which is the printing edition of the siddur the Rebbe used.

Comment: Can you source that this wasn't in the siddur by the alter rebbe?

Comment: It was included in the Siddur, and in fact we even have a Ksav Yad of the Alter Rebbe in which he writes a version of Hanosein Teshuah

Comment: http://www.shturem.net/index.php?section=blog_new&article_id=206

Comment: See also the book "הסידור" on the Alter Rebbe's siddur (sorry I don't have it with me nor do I have access to Otzar at this momen) in which the Ksav Yad is printed along with an ensuing discussion